# mean(POP) in pythonic syntax?

Tags: python, matlab, population

I have an assignment that contains this code from `matlab`, and I would like to know the syntax of that function in Python. It's used to know the mean of binary numbers:

```
mean(POP)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to port matlab code to python, consider using the packages [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), [scipy](http://www.scipy.org) and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) which between them cover a large part of matlab functionality. As it happens, numpy includes a function `numpy.mean` which computes the mean of a numpy array or a list. Example:

```
import numpy
print(numpy.mean([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Comment: in case you're in an windows platform you could resort to Anaconda: https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

Answer (score 0):

A few versions that come to mind are the following:

```
mean1 = lambda x: 1.0*sum(x)/len(x)

def mean2(x):
    return 1.0*sum(x)/len(x)

def mean3(*args):
    return 1.0*sum(args)/len(args)
```

Here, `mean1` and `mean2` do exactly the same, but the first function is defined as a lambda expression. They both take a list as an argument, use the `sum` function to calculate the sum of all the elements and the `len` function to know how many elements are in the list. To be safe, I multiply with 1.0 so that the division will always yield a floating point number. This is not necessary in Python 3 where the `/` operation will always produce a floating point number and never an integer.

So these two versions can be used as follows:

```
mean1([1,2,3,4])
mean2([1,2,3,4])
```

and would produce the result `2.5`.

In the third version, you don't need to specify a list, you can just use a number of arguments to the function:

```
mean3(1,2,3,4)
```

which would again return `2.5`.